# Finding strings 'ab1cd', 'ab2cd', 'ab3cd', and 'ab4cd' with just one click

Tags: find

I have a .txt file. In this file, I want to find all the strings that begins with 'ab', have exactly one character following it, and ends with 'cd'. Namely, 'ab*cd'. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's tab. I'm trying to use grep, but terminal won't accept tab as an input... Maybe I should Find & Replace all tabs into commas and try grepping again?

Comment: Tell your terminal to take the next character literally. In *nix it's usually Ctrl-V to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual suspect for finding text in a file is [**grep**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). grep takes [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

```
grep 'ab.cd' input.txt
```

Comment: Notepad++ also takes regular expressions.

Comment: In case you are wondering, what `. (dot is called period) ` does `It matches any single character.`